# puzzling behavior using dropzone

Tags: php, dropzone

I needed drag and drop provision for uploading files in a site i am creating.
I added dropzone for this and  implemented it successfully.
I am using Bracket for coding.
However i noticed a strange behavior - as long as i use live preview in bracket , drop zone work perfectly.
However if i run the site in the browser directly it does not work at all - as if this functionality is
missing in the site.
I have copied source code from browser in both case through live preview and directly and compared them.
There is no visible difference except a script added by KasperskyIS AV - which is used in both pages but the attribute used in the link both page is different.
I would like to know did some one faced such issue using drop zone - with out drop zone site works similarly in both live preview in bracket and using directly in browser.
Hope i have some answer, i can message for the particular page to anyone who believe he/she can help.
Sorry if this is not in the protocol of StackOverflow but i have my limitation right on on sharing code.
Thanks

Comment: What are the errors you are getting, at least show those here.

Comment: I am not getting any error.
Hovering mouse over dropzone or click on dropzone has no response at all .

Comment: Clicking on dropzone should browse file system so that you can select a file. And if you drag a file over dropzone it whould allow you to drop file over there and start uploading.
But nothing like this happens if run the site directly instead of live preview in Brackets.

Comment: I just noticed it does not allow browse and select but does allow drag and drop.
However it allows all type of files to be accepted and instead of uploading it show the file in a new tab.I have coded to allow a particular file extension only and its working ok when used through live preview in Bracket.

Comment: Are you sure the scripts are loaded?

Comment: Sorry  I did not mentioned that.
I am working on localhost.I am yet to upload this to any onlne server.